# Can Node sites be hosted as a "standard" site?

Tags: node.js, npm

So I have run on the LAMP stack forever and wanted to switch to node.  There is a ton of npm resources I wanted to start using.  I realize this is a totally noob question...

If I make a site on node, can it be built as just a static HTML/javascript site so I can just ftp it up to any ol hosting provider as an HTML site?

Comment: What use do you have for Node if it's a static site? Do you want it for task automation or something?

Comment: Static site not static content.   This means I am not dynamically generating pages from the server.  The files hosted are static HTML and javascript.   Client side, the page content may or may not be dynamic.

Comment: I know what static means... if you already have a host, and you're only serving static files, then Node.js is not necessary.

Comment: Dude... please read the question fully... the are node packages I would like to use that arent available as just js source files.

Answer (score 1):

No, node.js runs an actual web/app server like Twisted. It's not like it's running the server in your webbrowser. The "LAMP" acronym would be: LNMJ.